# raspiberry zero and esp32

Tags: pi-zero

i want to send file computer to esp32 via wifi connection and it write file to sd card.(Tutorial link: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OkEXeRbq_M) ) But there is a problem. It's esp32 ram value is low. It can be a problem because my time is limited. Thus i thought that maybe i can use esp32 with raspiberry zero. Is it possible ? Can i send file via esp32 wifi and file will be writed raspiberry sd card. If it is possible, how can i do it?

Comment: Is your goal to get a file on an SD card, and the esp32 is a mechanism, or something else.  If the goal is getting a file on the card, there are many ways to do that, depending on the file system on the card.

Comment: What is esp32 ?